# Hibernate 6.2 throws `"targetModelPart" is null` exception when trying to migrate from 5.x

Tags: java, java-17, hibernate-6.x, spring-boot-3

I am trying to migrate a legacy application from spring boot 2.5 to 3.1.5 (latest as of now).

This is par@JsonIgnore

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "TICKER_SERIAL", referencedColumnName = "TICKER_SERIAL", insertable = false, updatable = false),
})
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
private Set<FundTickerDescription> fundTickerDescriptions;


@JsonProperty("INDEX_BENCHMARK")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "TICKER_SERIAL", referencedColumnName = "TICKER_SERIAL")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
private List<FundBenchmarkV2> fundBenchmarkV2s;
```

For these 2 lists hibernate is throwing following exceptions:

```
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: DFN_CONTENT_DATA] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PostInitCallback queue could not be processed...
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping( NavigableRole[com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.fundtickers.TickerV3.fundBenchmarkV2s#{element}]) - element descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping(com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.fundtickers.TickerV3.fundBenchmarkV2s) - key descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping( NavigableRole[com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.fundtickers.TickerV3.fundTickerDescriptions#{element}]) - element descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping(com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.fundtickers.TickerV3.fundTickerDescriptions) - key descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping( NavigableRole[com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.tickers.TickersAll.stockEligibilities#{element}]) - element descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping(com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.tickers.TickersAll.stockEligibilities) - key descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping( NavigableRole[com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.tickers.TickersAll.tickerDescriptions#{element}]) - element descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping(com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.tickers.TickersAll.tickerDescriptions) - key descriptor

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PostInitCallback queue could not be processed...
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping( NavigableRole[com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.fundtickers.TickerV3.fundBenchmarkV2s#{element}]) - element descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping(com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.fundtickers.TickerV3.fundBenchmarkV2s) - key descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping( NavigableRole[com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.fundtickers.TickerV3.fundTickerDescriptions#{element}]) - element descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping(com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.fundtickers.TickerV3.fundTickerDescriptions) - key descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping( NavigableRole[com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.tickers.TickersAll.stockEligibilities#{element}]) - element descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping(com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.tickers.TickersAll.stockEligibilities) - key descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping( NavigableRole[com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.tickers.TickersAll.tickerDescriptions#{element}]) - element descriptor
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - PluralAttributeMapping(com.mubasher.ccp.library.entities.tickers.TickersAll.tickerDescriptions) - key descriptor

    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.execute(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 80 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.PropertyBasedMapping.getPropertyAccess()" because "targetModelPart" is null
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.<init>(SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.interpretPluralAttributeMappingKeyDescriptor(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.lambda$buildPluralAttributeMapping$3(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:692)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess$PostInitCallbackEntry.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:106)
        ... 90 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.PropertyBasedMapping.getPropertyAccess()" because "targetModelPart" is null
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.<init>(SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.interpretPluralAttributeMappingKeyDescriptor(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.lambda$buildPluralAttributeMapping$3(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:692)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess$PostInitCallbackEntry.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:106)
        ... 90 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.PropertyBasedMapping.getPropertyAccess()" because "targetModelPart" is null
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.<init>(SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.interpretPluralAttributeMappingKeyDescriptor(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.lambda$buildPluralAttributeMapping$3(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:692)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess$PostInitCallbackEntry.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:106)
        ... 90 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.PropertyBasedMapping.getPropertyAccess()" because "targetModelPart" is null
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.<init>(SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.interpretPluralAttributeMappingKeyDescriptor(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationHelper.lambda$buildPluralAttributeMapping$3(MappingModelCreationHelper.java:692)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess$PostInitCallbackEntry.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:106)
        ... 90 common frames omitted
```

Now I don't want to bloat the question by adding all the entities. Please comment on any extra code snippets.

Here is a minified TickerDescription class:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TickerDescriptionV2Id.class)
@Table(name = "TICKER_DESCRIPTIONS", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ticker_id"})
})
public class TickerDescriptionsV2 {
    
    @JsonProperty("SHORT_DESCRIPTION")
    @Column(name = "SHORT_DESCRIPTION")
    private String shortDescription;

    @JsonProperty("LONG_DESCRIPTION")
    @Column(name = "LONG_DESCRIPTION")
    private String longDescription;

    @JsonProperty(value = "TICKER_ID", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "TICKER_ID")
    private String tickerId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "SOURCE_ID", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "SOURCE_ID")
    private String sourceId;

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("LANGUAGE_ID")
    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
    private String languageId;

    @Id
    @JsonProperty(value = "TICKER_SERIAL", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "TICKER_SERIAL")
    private Long tickerSerial;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @MapsId("TICKER_SERIAL")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TICKER_SERIAL", referencedColumnName = "TICKER_SERIAL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private TickerV3 ticker;

}
```

And here is the id class

```
@Embeddable
public class TickerDescriptionV2Id implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
    @JsonProperty(value = "LANGUAGE_ID")
    private String languageId;

    @Column(name = "TICKER_SERIAL")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long tickerSerial;
}
```

I think @Embeddable is not needed here. But it is written by some one else a long time ago.
I checked hibernate site and other questions. Nothing quite like the error message I am seeing. What's going wrong here?